# Inputting numbers into a public float array

Tags: java, console-application

I need to get two floats separated by a space so that I can use them in my calculator. I'm having trouble with the following error. I think I have to initialize the array first but whatever I do, I just get errors. The input should be like this:

Enter two floats separated by a space:
4.3 6.5

And once two numbers have been entered, the user presses Enter. I will implement a function to not allow the input if the user has entered anything but two numbers ("You've only entered one number, please try again and enter two:" Then it will prompt the user again for two numbers.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

These are the two classes that relate to inputting the numbers:

CalculatorMain class:

```
    public class CalculatorMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int OP; float num1, num2;
float result;
System.out.println("Welcome, " + System.getProperty("user.name") + ", to the Calculator application.");
System.out.println("Begin by entering the number of the operator you would like to use:\n");
CalculatorOperator.printOptions();
OP = CalculatorInput.getOP();
CalculatorInput.getNums();
num1 = CalculatorInput.inputs[0];
num2 = CalculatorInput.inputs[1];
result = CalculatorOperator.switcher(OP, num1, num2);
System.out.println("The result is:\n" + result + "\nWould you like to use the calculator again?");
}
```

}

CalculatorInput class:

```
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CalculatorInput {
public static float[] inputs;

public static void getNums() {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter two floats seperated by a space:\n");
    while(in.hasNext()){
        for(int c = 0; c <=2; c++){
            inputs[c] = in.nextFloat();
        }
    }
    in.close();
}

public static int getOP() {
    int OP;
    Scanner inOP = new Scanner(System.in);
    OP = inOP.nextInt();
    inOP.close();
    return OP;
}
}
```

Comment: In your `CalculatorInput` Class, where do you initialize your `float[] inputs`? Like setting the size of the array. I.E: `inputs = new float[size]`. Also I don't think you fully understand the proper usage of `static` in Classes that don't contain a `main` method.

Comment: I think you need to change the word operator to operand as well.

Comment: If you step through this with a debugger, you will most likely see your error immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your array:

```
... float[] inputs = new float[2];
```

That should solve your NullPointerException.

Also, your for loop has the wrong limits. It should be from `int c = 0` to `c < 2`, otherwise you'll wait for three floats (0, 1 and 2), not two.

Comment: I've done that and I no longer get that error, now I'm getting something that's happened before whilst I was trying to solve this. 

Enter two floats seperated by a space:

The result is:
0.0
Would you like to use the calculator again?

As soon as I enter the operator I want to use, it doesn't wait for me to input the numbers, it just thinks the numbers are both 0s?

Comment: @Ashford, you better be more specific with your questions. Posting a new question in comments is not very helpful. I suggest you read more and understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not sure how I'm posting a new question. My title suggests that I need help inputting two floats and that comment is elaborating to the original question.

Comment: I understand but it would be better for you to just post the requirements and some initial code and let people help you. The way you did it is post a generic title, with some very bad/incomplete code. That's not helping people help you. That's why people are voting your question down.

Comment: @Ashford Don't close the Scanner. It closes System.in.